# Android animating a WebView with many webView.LoadData calls

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

In writing cross platform software, I made the design decision to write the the views once in HTML so they would be the same on the website, iOS and andorid apps. I'm trying to display them on Android with a  WebView.

The views are animated, and so I generate new HTML at least 10 times a second and update them with:

```
webView.LoadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
webView.PostInvaldiate();
```

However, the Web View only seems to update once every 2 seconds, at its **quickest**.
Am I completely overloading the UI Thread? I'm assuming WebViews were never designed for this.
Is it possible to display an animated view like this (using HTML) in Android, or do I need to cut my losses and go back and rewrite the whole thing using an android canvas or something?

Also inviting comments as to how idiotic this design decision was!

Comment: webView won't be able to do it, even when it's hardware accelerated it's way too slow.

Comment: @Pawel I think you're right - write this as an answer and I'll accept it - it answers my question.

Comment: Why don't you just animate it in an HTML file and load the HTML once

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT unfortunately the animation is decided in real-time according to other factors the webview can't know

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Or you can use https://github.com/crosswalk-project . It has better graphics features. You can generate project via `npm` or (second preferred) use `gradle` dependency and use `CrossWalkView` as your simple WebView.

Also try one more extended webview lib: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4873

Comment: Giving it a go now

Comment: I was looking into Crosswalk project, but on Xamarin I needed a new plugin for different Android architectures - ARM and x86

Comment: I can't - I'm using Xamarin android not native Android